# Show more information in the "GroupingField" of the AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

When i use the AdvancedDataGrid in Flex4.6, i want to show my data like this:

```
-AA  |  AAInfo1 | AAInfo2 |
  aa |  aaInfo1 | aaInfo2 |
  bb |  bbInfo1 | bbInfo2 |
  cc |  ccInfo1 | ccInfo2 |
-BB  |  BBInfo1 | BBInfo2 |
  dd |  ddInfo1 | ddInfo2 |
  ee |  eeInfo1 | eeInfo2 |
```

But i found that i could not use the rows in the "GroupingField" level, and i could only do it like this:

```
-AA  |          |         |
  aa |  aaInfo1 | aaInfo2 |
  bb |  bbInfo1 | bbInfo2 |
  cc |  ccInfo1 | ccInfo2 |
-BB  |          |         |
  dd |  ddInfo1 | ddInfo2 |
  ee |  eeInfo1 | eeInfo2 |
```

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Please put whatever you have done uptil now.... Else we not gonna understand where you are facing problem

Comment: ...I just solve this problem.Thank you anyway.